# Cakephp 3 - Associations: 3 foreing keys in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, associations

I have 2 tables, `BAR` and `UNTRS`, UNTRS have 3 FK `(BARR_1, BARR_2 & BARR_3)` that references to `BAR.COD_ID (primary key)`.
But every FK references to a different row of BAR.

**I'm trying to make a association that results in a a SQL query with a JOIN like this:**

```
LEFT JOIN UNTRS ON (
    UNTRS.BARR_1 = (BAR.COD_ID)
    OR UNTRS.BARR_2 = (BAR.COD_ID)
    OR UNTRS.BARR_3 = (BAR.COD_ID)
);
```

**Or something like this:**

```
LEFT JOIN UNTRS UNTRS_1 ON UNTRS_1.BARR_1 = BAR.COD_ID
LEFT JOIN UNTRS UNTRS_2 ON UNTRS_2.BARR_2 = BAR.COD_ID
LEFT JOIN UNTRS UNTRS_3 ON UNTRS_3.BARR_3 = BAR.COD_ID
```

---

I already tried:

BARTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('UNTRS', [
        'className'    => 'UNTRS',
        'bindingKey'   => ['BARR_1', 'BARR_2', 'BARR_3'],
        'foreignKey'   => ['COD_ID', 'COD_ID', 'COD_ID'],
        'strategy'     => 'join',
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'unidade_transformadora_subestacao'
    ]);
```

And this is the result JOIN in the SQL query:

```
LEFT JOIN UNTRS UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10 ON (
    UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10.BARR_1 = (BarramentosModulo10.COD_ID)
    AND UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10.BARR_2 = (BarramentosModulo10.COD_ID)
    AND UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10.BARR_3 = (BarramentosModulo10.COD_ID)
);
```

I tried this too:

BARTable.php

```
$this->belongsTo('UNTRS_1', [
        'className'    => 'UNTRS',
        'foreignKey'   => ['COD_ID'],
        'bindingKey'   => ['BARR_1'],
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'unidade_transformadora_subestacao_primeira'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('UNTRS_2', [
        'className'    => 'UNTRS',
        'foreignKey'   => ['COD_ID'],
        'bindingKey'   => ['BARR_2'],
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'unidade_transformadora_subestacao_segunda'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('UNTRS_3', [
        'className'    => 'UNTRS',
        'foreignKey'   => ['COD_ID'],
        'bindingKey'   => ['BARR_3'],
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'unidade_transformadora_subestacao_terceira'
    ]);
```

And with that code, `cakephp` don't make the JOIN on the result SQL query.

Edit:
I tried this code too:

UNTRSTable.php

```
$this->hasMany('UNTRS1', [
        'className'    => 'UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10',
        'bindingKey'   => 'BARR_1',
        'foreignKey'   => 'COD_ID',
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'untrs1'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('UNTRS2', [
        'className'    => 'UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10',
        'bindingKey'   => 'BARR_2',
        'foreignKey'   => 'COD_ID',
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'untrs2'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('UNTRS3', [
        'className'    => 'UnidadesTransformadorasSubestacaoModulo10',
        'bindingKey'   => 'BARR_3',
        'foreignKey'   => 'COD_ID',
        'joinType'     => 'LEFT',
        'propertyName' => 'untrs3'
    ]);
```

Again, the query don't contain the JOINS.

Comment: Your separate `belongsTo` examples should work, as in they should cause joins to be generated. How exactly do you query the data (in terms of preparing the query builder)? `hasMany` (just like `belongsToMany`) will not create joins, it will use separate queries!

Comment: Hi @ndm, thanks for answering. This the query builder in my code:  
.
`return $this->find('all')
        ->contain(['UNTRS1', 'UNTRS2', 'UNTRS3'])
        ->where($where)
        ->bufferResults(false);`

Comment: Well that should certainly work assuming the contained names are matching the association names, your `belongsTo` ones have an underscore (note that [**disabling result buffering**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets) won't work properly with `hasMany`).

Comment: A quick test with your exact example code shows that the joins are being generated just fine. Are you sure that you're looking at the correct query log, and that whatever code that calls that finder is actually being invoked in the first place? Also try checking `$query->sql()` (on the query that contains the `belongsTo` associations).

Comment: I found the error, the code have an verification to see if the association become to the correct model before get the contain() array.

Comment: `#RelatedUnidades() returns: ['UNTRS1', 'UNTRS2', 'UNTRS3'];

foreach ($this->getRelatedUnidades() as $key => $modeloContain) {
            dump(TableRegistry::get($modeloContain));
            if(in_array(TableRegistry::get($modeloContain)->table(),$tableList)) {
                $contain[] = $modeloContain;
                dump($modeloContain);
            }
            
        }`